# @RenderBody() in MVC4 interfering with twitter bootstrap responsive css

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

Building a site using ASP.NET MVC 4.5, and using twitter's bootstrap-responsive. I noticed that on re-sizing the page, anything rendered by the _Layout view covers what I have rendered using the @RenderBody() statement. Is there any way to correct this?

Comment: This is too vague to answer. Show the HTML with which you can reproduce the problem, and explain what you expect to see and what you do see. It's not like "Oh, when you resize a page rendered with a _Layout and @RenderBody() your rendering gets messed up, put this `<meta />` tag and it'll be fixed".

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure, but your problem probably isn't a consequence of @RenderBody. @RenderBody renders the content of your page that isn't in a section. The issue is probably a consequence of which twitter-bootstrap classes style the layout.

All I can do it point you to http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html (until the abbreviated html code is included).